# Event.target.dataset returning undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener, custom-data-attribute

I am getting some issues while trying to get the **data** attribute of any html element.

The problem is i am getting the data attribute in **30%** of the cases. The rest is returning undefined.

Here's what i want to trigger:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
        console.log("clicked");
        console.log(e.target.dataset.link + " is the link clicked") // this is returning undefined most of the times.
        if (e.target.dataset.link !== undefined) {
            console.log("got the link")
            navigateTo(e.target.dataset.link);
        }
    })

    // router();
})
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-link="/dashboard/posts" tabindex="1">
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
    <span>Posts</span>
 </div>
```

How is this even possible ?

And how can i prevent this ?

I can't remove the onclick event listener for the body.

Comment: Please do not recreate link functionality using a div. Just use the `a` element

Comment: @evolutionbox I am building a SPA so I had to do this. I am not using any react or something. Just created my own.

Comment: I don't think you had to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.target` is the element the event was targeted at, which may be **inside** your `data-link` element (like the `i` and `span` in your `div`). You can use the [`closest` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with an attribute presence selector ([`[attribute-name]`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation)) to find the `data-link` element:

```
const dataElement = e.target.closest("[data-link]");
```

That checks `e.target` to see if it matches the CSS selector and, if it doesn't, looks to its parent to see if *it* matches, and so on until it reaches the document root. If it gets all the way to the root without finding it, it returns `null`.

Updated Snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
        const dataElement = e.target.closest("[data-link]");
        if (!dataElement) {
            return; // There wasn't one
        }
        console.log(dataElement.dataset.link + " is the link clicked") // this is returning undefined most of the times.
        if (dataElement.dataset.link !== undefined) {
            console.log("got the link")
            // navigateTo(dataElement.dataset.link);
        }
    })

    // router();
})
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-link="/dashboard/posts" tabindex="1">
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
    <span>Posts</span>
 </div>
```

---

**However**, please note [evolutionxbox's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195994/event-target-dataset-returning-undefined-javascript/70196050#comment124087737_70195994). You're recreating basic web functionality using non-semantic elements and JavaScript code. That destroys the [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG) of your page, and even for users who don't rely on assistive technology, it makes it impossible for them to use the advanced features of their browser to (say) open the link in a new tab, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You attach the event listener to the document body.
Is absolutely normal that you don't get the dataset: you can click out of the *cell*, or in a element into this.

You need attach the event to the desired elements with the  `data-link` attribute:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-link]').forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        console.log("clicked");
        console.log(node.dataset.link + " is the link clicked")
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="cell" data-link="/dashboard/posts">
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
    <span>Posts</span>
 </div>
 

<div class="cell">
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
    <span>Posts</span>
 </div>
```